# beautifulsoupでbodyタグの中身が取得できない

Tags: python, html, python3, beautifulsoup

スクレイピングをしたいのですが、
ここのサイトのbodyタグの中身をfindChirdrenで取得したいのですがnoneと表示され取得できません。

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    def _get_page(url):
        #r変数に<!DOCTYPE html>から代入する。
        r = requests.get(url)
        #レスポンスコードが200で正常だったら文字列""にして返す。
        r.encoding = r.apparent_encoding
        if r.status_code == 200:
            print(r.text)
            body_soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser").find('body')
            print(body_soup)


    _get_page('https://www.intel.co.jp/content/www/jp/ja/homepage.html?_ga=2.148658167.1198309579.1498475512-1466255303.1498475512')
```

**エラー**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/vagrant/test2.py", line 60, in <module>
    _get_page(url)
  File "/vagrant/test2.py", line 56, in _get_page
    for child_tag in body_soup.findChildren():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findChildren'
```

r.textは表示されるのでhtmlは取得できているのですが、bodyタグの中身はnoneと表示され取得できません。
googleなど他のサイトなどではしっかり取得する事ができます。
詳しい方ご回答をよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「r.textは表示されるのでhtmlは取得できているのですが、bodyタグの中身はnoneと表示され取得できません」というのは、print(r.text)だとhtmlが表示されるのに、print(body_soup)では何も表示されないという事ですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

簡易パーザーである`html.parser`ではパーズに失敗してまともに読み込めないぐらい、元のhtmlの構造が複雑 もしくは 壊れているということです。
環境によっては難しいかもしれませんが、`lxml`を指定すると動くことは動く(*)ので可能なら`lxml`を使うべきです。

(*)htmlの構造がおかしいので、その影響はありますが。

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def _get_page(url):
    #r変数に<!DOCTYPE html>から代入する。
    r = requests.get(url)
    #レスポンスコードが200で正常だったら文字列""にして返す。
    r.encoding = r.apparent_encoding
    if r.status_code == 200:
        return BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml").find('body')

_get_page('https://www.intel.co.jp/content/www/jp/ja/homepage.html?_ga=2.148658167.1198309579.1498475512-1466255303.1498475512')
```

REPLでの結果

```
<body><div class="clientcontext parbase"><script type="text/javascript">
    $CQ(function() {
        CQ_Analytics.SegmentMgr.loadSegments("\/etc\/segmentation");
        CQ_Analytics.ClientContextUtils.init("\/etc\/clientcontext\/intel", "\/content\/www\/jp\/ja\/homepage");


    });
</script>
</div>
<div class="analytics">
</div>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/etc/designs/intel/clientlibs/pages/commons-page-ieOverrides.min.css" type="text/css">

    <![endif]-->
<link href="/etc/designs/intel/jp/ja/css/intel.rwd.override.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/designs/intel/clientlibs/pages/commons-page-ieOverrides.min.js"></script>

    <![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isTargetEnabled=false;
</script>
（略)
```

Answer (score 0):

上記プログラムで取得しているページ( https://www.intel.co.jp/content/www/jp/ja/homepage.html )のステータスコードが304なので、if文で弾かれているためです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。chromeとbeatifulsoupで確認したのですがどちらともステータスコードは200でした。そしてhtmlファイルは取得できています。その中にbodyタグもあるのですがなぜかエラーが出てしまします。